# How to write a paragraph in Arabic in html?

Tags: php, html

Here is the code I use to write a paragraph in Arabic, but it does not work:

```
<p lang="ar" dir="rtl">....paragraph in Arabic.... </p>
```

this code displays `?????????`

I use UTF-8 as the encoding type, and PSPad as editor.

Please do you have an idea about that?

Comment: do you have a link to your page? or show us your full html generated

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="info">
                 <div align=right dir=rtl>
                 .....paraghraph in Arabic
               
                 </div>

  </body>
</html>

Comment: Please don't post additional information in comments. Use the edit link below your question to include additional information. Don't forgett to delete the comment afterwards

Comment: You need to spacify language in your html element
<html lang="ar">

Comment: @CodingHorror The wrong language shouldn't stop the browser from displaying the correct chars.

Comment: have you tried other editors? for example notePad or notePad++,?

Comment: Does the font you use in the browser support arabic script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use UTF-8, you need to tell the browser. If you use a server, you can do this directly with the HTTP protocol by adding `; charset=utf-8` after the `Content-Type` value, so the value could for example be `text/html; charset=utf-8`. If you don't use a Server or couldn't modify that variable, you can add this in the `head` tag of your HTML page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

You can also try this:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

Comment: I have already added this, But it still does not work :(

Comment: @AhmedBenmessoud Did you try `<meta charset="UTF-8" />`? That's the way Wikipedia does and it works

Comment: I think his problem is related to PSPad

Comment: @Ahmad If PSPad produces valid UTF-8 output that wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @AhmedBenmessoud Please also check that your editor produces valid UTF-8 output, maybe check with another editor like notpad++ (windows) or kate (GNU/Linux)

Comment: @msed0 yes I tried with notepad ++ but it displays "????" Instead of the text in Arabic,i think that this problem comes from the edito

Comment: @AhmedBenmessoud Then I would recommend that you check which encoding your editor uses if it isn't utf-8

Comment: after I edited the format at the édireur, I put "UTF-8" instead of "ANSI" it works very well now, thank you for your answers. thank @msrd0 :)

Answer (score 1):

Try put this before you echo anything to output stream on server php side:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: @msrd0 your edit change nothing. spaces in php code bring nothing to the browser

Comment: Yes, my edit was usefull because your code now gets highlighted by Stack Overflow's syntax highlighter. For more information see the help center.

Comment: it changes nothing I still have the same problem! :(

Comment: @AhmedBenmessoud The answer is correct but your file isn't encoded using utf-8